# Is it possible to change strings using Dotfuscator?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, obfuscation, dotfuscator

I have secret string in my code like that "1WDF-2HJH-4HJ5"

```
if(Checker() == "1WDF-2HJH-4HJ5")
return false;
```

Is it possible somehow to replace that string during dotfuscation?
I am using Dotfuscator Community Edition 5.54521

May be there is another ways to hide sensitive strings?

Comment: You do realize that obfuscation is won't actually hide the sensitive string, right? It will just make it somewhat harder to retrieve.

Comment: No. Obfuscation does not change the functionality of a program. It might rename Checker(), but it won't change the string. From wikipedia "Obfuscation is the hiding of intended meaning, making communication confusing, wilfully ambiguous, and harder to interpret."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disclaimer:  I'm an employee of the company that makes Dotfuscator.

Dotfuscator does provide a feature called String Encryption which will mangle the string as it appears in the code, then turn it back into the original string at runtime.  Unfortunately, this feature isn't available in the Community Edition of Dotfuscator.  It is only available in the Pro editions.